# Create custom merge tag for Day, Month and Year of Date field in Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, date, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms Plugin for forms in WordPress site. Gravity Forms have have lots of merge tag by default for various field.

Gravity Forms have Date Field for inserting date but merge tag shows like this:
`{Date:1}` but I need separate merge tag for Day Month and Year of Date field.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the day, month and year modifiers with the field merge tag e.g. {Date:1:day}.